# jQuery- Generate link names from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I´m using the [jQuery UI tooltip script](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).
Therefore I have tooltip links with different "data-id" values like that:

```
<a tooltip-link data-id="12555"></a>
<a tooltip-link data-id="38"></a>
```

The "data-id" values get sent with ajax to my server sided script and the ajax-results are shown in the tooltips.

Additionally I want to dynamically generate the **link names** out of a certain part of this ajax-response.

The part of the **ajax-response** which should be used for the link names is the content of every `<div class="">`  which contains parts of the `item-title` class:

**ajax response**

```
<div class="item-title">Item12555</div>
<div class="item-title3">Item38</div>
```

This is my working tooltip-jQuery script so far. How can I implement the generation of the link names?

```
 jQuery(function($) {   

  $( "[tooltip-link]" ).each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $(this).tooltip({
      tooltipClass: "test",
      content: function( response ) {
          $.ajax({ 
          url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
          data: {
                  'var': id
              },
          type: "GET"
          })
            .then(function( data ) {
               response( data );
            });
      },
      items: "*"
    });
  })

});
```

Comment: What do the *ajax-results* look like? And what parts of those result do you want to use in the `response`?

Comment: I want to use the content inside of the `<div class="item-title">`. This should be the name of my links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select and create elements with the jQuery selector `$()`. Pass a string to the selector while combining the strings with the `data` from the response and the `id` from the data attribute.

The `content` property function is called every time you hover over a tooltip element. This will invoke an `$.ajax` call for every hover which will be very expensive.

Turn it around by doing the AJAX requests first and set the `data` from the request as the value of the `content` property.

As for the `<div class="item-title">` just append it to the anchor element that is stored in the `$tooltip` variable.

And last, the tooltip elements need a `title` attribute in the HTML. This is not clearly documented, but it won't work without the attribute. There doesn't need to be a value in the title.

```
<a tooltip-link data-id="12555" title=""></a>
```

```
jQuery(function($) {
  
  $("[tooltip-link]").each(function() {
    let $tooltip = $(this);
    let id = $tooltip.attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        "var": id
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      let $content = $(data);
      let title = $content.find('.item-title3').text()

      $tooltip.tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "test",
        content: data
      });

      $tooltip.append(title);
    });
  });
    
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have a stupid question. How can I get the `$content` inside of the `<a tooltip-link data-id="12555"></a>`  tag? So I can see the link name.

Comment: There's no thing like a stupid question. I'm looking into it and come back to with an answer soon.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it helps out.

Comment: Thank you. The content of the `<div class="item-title">` is now the link. But sadly the tooltip isn´t working anymore, when I hover over the link. The content of the tooltip is now under the link. I´ve set up a test page. Maybe you find the time to look at. I really appreciate your help. Test site: [link](https://wildstar-mmo.de/index.php/tooltip)

Comment: The tooltip element needs a `title` attribute to work. The value of the attribute can be empty. The `content` property value will replace the value of the `title` anyway.

Comment: I understand. The tooltip is working again now. One last question. As you can see the whole content of the tooltip is under the link of the `<div class="item-title">` now. It shouldn´t be there and only be visible within the tooltip.

Comment: Ah, I figured thats what you meant. Just remove the `$("<div class=\"item-title\">" + data + "</div>")` line or change `data` into another value in that line to change the content of the inserted div.

Comment: I follow. you. If I want the content of the `<div class="item-title">` means the title as the link name, and not the `id`, do I have to make a new variable for that or what would be the general idea for that?

Comment: Ah, I think I'm following. You'll need to turn the `data` into a jQuery object to be able to select elements from it, at least with jQuery. Then find the element with the `.item-title` class and extract the contents. Then append it to the tooltip.

Comment: Sadly it seems that it can´t find `.item-title` element. I´ve updated the test page.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that element is present in your AJAX response?

Comment: Yes, when I check the Browsers Developers Tools- > Network -> XHR (Response) it shows me for example: `<div class="item-title3">xy</div>`. Here you can see it: [link](https://wildstar-mmo.de/index.php/tooltip)

Comment: `item-title3` isn't the same as `item-title`. Either remove the `3` from the response or add `3` in the jQuery selector.

Comment: I´ve added now the 3 to `item-title3`, but it still seems that it can´t be found. That´s strange.